# Looping over swiper-slides excluding cloned duplicates in cypress

Tags: vue.js, cypress, cypress-each

I am new to Cypress and trying to loop the swiper slides excluding cloned duplicates. I am using the index of .each() in cypress but this is not working. Below is my code

```
if (index != 0 && index >= 22) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Below is the example snapshot of my html code:
[image]

Can anyone please suggest the logic to loop only into the original slides?

Comment: What does "not working" look like? And please add the full test.

Comment: I want to exclude duplicate slides, I have put a condition in if to get first 22 slides, but it is taking a count of duplicate slides too

Comment: Trying to ask we have any method in Cypress where we can exclude the web elements using a class name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:not()` pseudo-selector

```js
cy.get('div.swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-duplicate)')
  .should('have.length', 23)   // to show loop is filtered, remove once confirmed
  .each($swiperSlide => {
    ...
```

or if you prefer to check inside the loop use `.not()` method

```js
cy.get('div.swiper-slide')
  .each($swiperSlide => {
    if ($swiperSlide.not(".swiper-slide-duplicate").length) {

    } else {

    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery `hasClass()` method with negation to check that the class `.swiper-slide-duplicate` is not present.

```js
cy.get('div.swiper-slide').each(($ele) => {
  if(!$ele.hasClass(".swiper-slide-duplicate")){
    //Do something when you don't have the duplicate slide
  }
  else {
    //Do something when you have the duplicate slide
  }
})
```

You can also reverse the check as well, first, you check the presence of the class `.swiper-slide-duplicate` and then in the else condition you can mention the things when you don't have the duplicate slide.

```js
cy.get('div.swiper-slide').each(($ele) => {
  if($ele.hasClass(".swiper-slide-duplicate")){
    //Do Something when you have the duplicate slide
  }
  else {
    //Do Something when you don't have the duplicate slide
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.attr()` method to check if the class is just `swiper-slide` or has both `swiper-slide` and `swiper-slide-duplicate`.

```js
cy.get('div.swiper-slide')
  .each($el => {
    if($el.attr("class") === "swiper-slide") {

    }
    else {

    }
  })
```

Same approach for `data-swiper-slide-index`

```js
cy.get('div.swiper-slide')
  .each($el => {
    if($el.attr("class") === "swiper-slide" && $el.attr("data-swiper-slide-index") !== "0") {

    }
    else {

    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery `.filter()` to process each type

```js
cy.get('div.swiper-slide')
  .then($els => {

    // Process non-duplicates
    $els.filter('[class=["swiper-slide"]') // exact match to a single class
      .each($el => {

      })

    // Process duplicates
    $els.filter('[class*=["swiper-slide-duplicate"]') // *= means "contains"
      .each($el => {

      })
  })
```

or in Cypress commands (without jQuery)

```js
// Process non-duplicates
cy.get('div.swiper-slide')
  .filter(':not(".swiper-slide-duplicate")')
  .each($el => {
    ...
  })

// Process duplicates
cy.get('div.swiper-slide')
  .filter('.swiper-slide-duplicate')
  .each($el => {
    ...
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop only into the original slides, use the Cypress [.not() command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/not#Examples) to exclude duplicates.

```js
cy.get('div.swiper-slide')
  .not('.swiper-slide-duplicate')
  .each($el => {
    ...
  })
```